# Trouble with subquery but only in view

Tags: mysql, subquery, database-performance

I have some trouble with the following query:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS own_inst_stakes_detail_all;
CREATE VIEW `own_inst_stakes_detail_all` AS 
SELECT 
    `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`FactSet_Entity_ID` AS `factset_entity_id`,
    `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`FSYM_ID` AS `fsym_id`,
    `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`as_of_date` AS `report_date`,
    `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`Position` AS `adj_holding`,
    `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`Position` / (SELECT own_sec_prices.adj_shares_outstanding FROM own_sec_prices WHERE own_sec_prices.`FSYM_ID` = own_inst_stakes_detail.`FSYM_ID` ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(own_sec_prices.price_date, `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`as_of_date`)) DESC LIMIT 1) AS `adj_ratio`,
    `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`Position` AS `reported_holding`,
    `sym_coverage`.`Proper_Name` AS `security_proper_name`,
    `sym_entity`.`Entity_Proper_Name` AS `entity_proper_name` 
FROM 
    `own_inst_stakes_detail` 
    LEFT JOIN `sym_entity` ON `sym_entity`.`FactSet_Entity_ID` = `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`FactSet_Entity_ID` 
    LEFT JOIN `sym_coverage` ON `sym_coverage`.`FSYM_ID` = `own_inst_stakes_detail`.`FSYM_ID`;
```

It uses the following tables, which are of particular interest:

```
CREATE TABLE `own_inst_stakes_detail` (
  `FactSet_Entity_ID` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `FSYM_ID` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `as_of_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `Position` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FactSet_Entity_ID`,`FSYM_ID`,`as_of_date`),
  KEY `idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FactSet_Entity_ID` (`FactSet_Entity_ID`),
  KEY `idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FSYM_ID` (`FSYM_ID`),
  KEY `idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_as_of_date` (`as_of_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `own_sec_prices` (
  `FSYM_ID` CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  `price_date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `unadj_shares_outstanding` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `adj_shares_outstanding` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FSYM_ID`,`price_date`),
  KEY `idx_own_sec_prices_FSYM_ID` (`FSYM_ID`),
  KEY `idx_own_sec_prices_price_date` (`price_date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query in the view works really well running just the query but it is a catastrophe if that is wrapped in a view. The query never completes, probably because of a full table scan. The tables are really big which I am using here.

I have tried that with MySQL Server 5.7 (btw., with MariaDB 10.1 there are no problems). Is there a way to improve that?

The EXPLAINs look as follows (Maria and My):

```
MariaDB [factset]> explain SELECT * FROM own_inst_stakes_detail_all WHERE FSYM_ID = 'WK13LJ-S' ORDER BY report_date DESC, adj_ratio DESC;
+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type        | table                  | type   | possible_keys                      | key                                | key_len | ref                                              | rows | Extra                                              |
+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY            | own_inst_stakes_detail | ref    | idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FSYM_ID | idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FSYM_ID | 8       | const                                            |    8 | Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | sym_entity             | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                            | 8       | factset.own_inst_stakes_detail.FactSet_Entity_ID |    1 |                                                    |
|    1 | PRIMARY            | sym_coverage           | const  | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                            | 8       | const                                            |    1 | Using where                                        |
|    3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | own_sec_prices         | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_own_sec_prices_FSYM_ID | idx_own_sec_prices_FSYM_ID         | 8       | factset.own_inst_stakes_detail.FSYM_ID           |   10 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
+------+--------------------+------------------------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT * FROM own_inst_stakes_detail_all WHERE FSYM_ID = 'WK13LJ-S' ORDER BY report_date DESC, adj_ratio DESC;
+----+--------------------+------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table                  | partitions | type   | possible_keys                      | key                        | key_len | ref                                              | rows   | filtered | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2>             | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>                        | <auto_key0>                | 8       | const                                            |     10 |   100.00 | Using where; Using filesort     |
|  2 | DERIVED            | own_inst_stakes_detail | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                               | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                                             | 817961 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  2 | DERIVED            | sym_entity             | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                    | 8       | factset.own_inst_stakes_detail.FactSet_Entity_ID |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  2 | DERIVED            | sym_coverage           | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                    | 8       | factset.own_inst_stakes_detail.FSYM_ID           |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                            |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | own_sec_prices         | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,idx_own_sec_prices_FSYM_ID | idx_own_sec_prices_FSYM_ID | 8       | factset.own_inst_stakes_detail.FSYM_ID           |     10 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+--------------------+------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.08 sec)
```

To me it looks like MySQL cannot use the index idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FSYM_ID. But if I change the column with the subquery to "1 as adj_ratio", the following happens:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM own_inst_stakes_detail_all WHERE FSYM_ID = 'WK13LJ-S';
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table                  | partitions | type   | possible_keys                      | key                                | key_len | ref                                              | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | own_inst_stakes_detail | NULL       | ref    | idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FSYM_ID | idx_own_inst_stakes_detail_FSYM_ID | 8       | const                                            |    8 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sym_entity             | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                            | 8       | factset.own_inst_stakes_detail.FactSet_Entity_ID |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sym_coverage           | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY                            | PRIMARY                            | 8       | const                                            |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+------------------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+---------+--------------------------------------------------+------+----------+-------+
3 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

That works well! Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW CREATE VIEW`, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for both MySQL and MariaDB.

Comment: Rick, thanks, I have added the statements zou asked for. Does that help?

Comment: Sounds like a case where MariaDB diverged in a better way.  Meanwhile, write a bug report at bugs.mysql.com against 5.7.